# Shell script: Excecute a command in "screen"

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, raspberry-pi

I use a USB-Dongle on my linux-server (raspberry).
To open the conecction and use the firmware, to do this, I have to open a terminal with "screen".

```
screen /dev/ttyACM0
```

There is no problem to open this connection with a shell script.
My problem is to execute a command in this screen.

The firmware has some command references for example V to get back the version number.

First of all, I tried a pipe (|)

```
screen /dev/ttyACM0 | echo "V"
```

But, this have no correct result.

Someone tell me I can use the screen command -X to execute something.

```
screen -T CUL /dev/ttyACM0
screen -X V
```

This seems to work.
The problem: "screen" gives an error message: -X: unknow command "V"

When I open the screen and entered the coammand V I get an output.

Some ideas?

Comment: Your pipe is backwards: `echo "V" | screen /dev/ttyACM0` should work, if typing "V" at the console of the device would executed a command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this command:

```
screen -X stuff 'V'$(printf \\r)
```

(you also need the carriage return)